# What’s the point of repeated class interface declaration in the implementation file?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

In some of the Apple Iphone examples, some of the properties are declared in the header file and some properties in the implementation file. For example in the Siesmic XML examples

ParseOperation.h

```
@interface ParseOperation : NSOperation {
NSData *earthquakeData;

@private
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter;

// these variables are used during parsing
Earthquake *currentEarthquakeObject;
Contact *currentContactObject;
NSMutableArray *currentParseBatch;
NSMutableString *currentParsedCharacterData;

BOOL accumulatingParsedCharacterData;
BOOL didAbortParsing;
NSUInteger parsedEarthquakesCounter;
}

@property (copy, readonly) NSData *earthquakeData;

@end
```

ParseOperation.m

```
@interface ParseOperation () <NSXMLParserDelegate>
  @property (nonatomic, retain) Earthquake *currentEarthquakeObject;
  @property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *currentParseBatch;
  @property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableString *currentParsedCharacterData;
  @property (nonatomic, retain) Contact *currentContactObject;
@end
```

What is the use of the additional interface declaration in the implementation file ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That’s simply a difference between a public and a private class interface. The header describes the public interface, but some of the properties are only meant to be used by the class itself, not by its collaborators. These private properties are usually declared the way you described, as a category or a class extension inside the implementation file.

```
// Foo.h – the public interface
@interface Foo : NSObject {…}

// Collaborators can only read bar.
@property(readonly) int bar;
@property(readonly) int baz;

@end

// Foo.m
#import "Foo.h"

// Private interface
@interface Foo ()

// Inside class implementation we can also change bar.
@property(assign) int bar;
@property(assign) int other;

@end

@implementation Foo
@synthesize bar, baz, other;
…
@end
```

Comment: Well - why not used the traditional private, public accessor modifiers ?

Comment: You don’t want to declare the variables public because it would break encapsulation. And sometimes you don’t want to access the variables directly even from the class implementation, since you would have to mess with memory management or you want the accessor to do something extra, like send KVO notifications or update other values.

Comment: hmmm.. so in theory, if "properties" also ha access modifiers, it would obviate the need to declare them in the implementation file. Right ?

Comment: Right. (If the access modifiers allowed you to make a property that’s read-write in the class implementation and read-ony for others.)

Comment: @zoul  In implementation foo class   add another  class like   interface foo1:nsobject { NSMutableArray *observers;
    CADisplayLink *displayLink;} - (void)removeObserver:(id)object;
implementation foo1  - (void)removeObserver:(id)object {
   nslog(@"%@",object);
}  how do i access the foo1 class removeObserver method?